# Is it possible to add a value to a submit button that gets passed in the params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm trying to add a "preview" button/page to my app.

Is there a way to add a different value to both my "post" and "preview" submit buttons that get passed in the params hash so that I can check which one was pressed in the controller and render the view accordingly?

Is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The keys of the `params` hash are just the `name` value of an element.

If you had two buttons named "submit", one with `value="post"` and `value="preview"`, then you could do something like:

```
if params[:submit] == "preview"
```

Comment: This solution is much better. I didn't know you could do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a button click event with javascript that will fill a hidden value and pass it along with the rest of your parameters. If using jQuery:

```
$("#post_button").click(function() {
   $("#form_action").val("post");
});

$("#preview_button").click(function() {
   $("#form_action").val("preview");
});
```

You'd then access the action in your controller using `params['form_action']`